# hide a view block if it has less than x results

Tags: views, hooks

I would like to make a slideshow on author pages if they write more than 10 articles on my site, otherwise no. 
I have created a views block containing the slideshow and i wonder how to automatically/programatically hide it if les than 10 articles were written . 
Thanks in advance for any help
Yaz

Comment: Will authors be allowed to do anything else if they have more than 10 posts? I'd consider giving them a role and basing views of that.

Comment: not especially. I just want to have a better looking page for those who post many articles rather than havin a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`template_preprocess_views_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x) in your `theme_name.theme` (assuming D8) or in your template.php

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['display_id'] == 'MY_DISPLAY_ID' && count($variables['view']->result) < 10) {
    $variables['view']->result = NULL;
  }
}
```

This is working for Drupal 7 and I assume it will for Drupal 8.
Be sure to check if your display is unique or you can also use the ID with :

```
$id = $variables['view']->storage->id(); // D8
```